# AWS: Boto SQS writing isn't saving

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm writing to SQS using boto as following.

[image]

I got the Message object response from print.

```
<boto.sqs.message.Message object at 0x102dd4790>
```

But I'm not seeing that message inside AWS SQS website?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQS is region specific. So using the following code to initialise sqs fixes this.

```
sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-2", aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```